# How does this password breaker work? can it also be adapted to suit other things?

Tags: vba, excel, password-encryption

I have had to use this code to remove passwords from protected sheets that no one knows the password to, I am interested to find out how it actually works and whether or not it can be tweaked to remove passwords from other Excel bits eg workbook structure or workbook passwords?

```
Sub PasswordBreaker()

'Breaks worksheet password protection.

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
On Error Resume Next
For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Chr(i) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
MsgBox "One usable password is " & Chr(i) & Chr(j) & _
Chr(k) & Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & _
Chr(i3) & Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
Exit Sub
End If
Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Looking at it - looks very similar to the code I have (copied from somewhere on the net).  As far as I know it will break the structure passwords, but not the workbook password.

Comment: I don't know VB, but this script appears to brute force with the expectation that all passwords are 12 characters long and that the first 11 of them are either A or B. Seems somewhat strange.

Comment: It is a dirty brute force, just look at ASC table to adjust the loops to include more characters. (replace `65 To 66` by `1 to 92` for instance, but keep in mind the number of test that it'll generate!!! Total number of possibilities = Product of each number of possibilies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be used to break anything except the password used to open a file.

The reason it works is that there is a vulnerability in the way Excel hashes passwords, so there are actually only 194K different hash values.

[Detailed Discussion](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/removepwords.html):
The reason is that the passwords you enter (i.e., with Tools/Protect/Protect Worksheet or /Protect Workbook) are not used directly in protection. Instead they are hashed (mathematically transformed) into a much less secure code. Effectively, any password of any length is transformed into a string of 12 characters, the first 11 of which have one of only two possible values. The remaining character can have up to 95 possible values, leading to only

```
2^11 * 95  = 194,560
```

potential passwords. This may seem like a lot, but it only takes a few seconds for a modern computer to try them all. As a comparison, a 4-character password containing just the 26 lower case alphabet characters has 456,976 combinations, and a 3-character password consisting of lower case, upper case and the digits 0-9 will have 238,328 combinations.

Again, it doesn't matter what your original password is, one of those 194K strings will unlock your sheet or workbook.